# 'It is I who is' or 'It is I who am'?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of these two sentences is correct?

> It is I who is foolish, not you.
>
> It is I who am foolish, not you.

(Incidentally, I am fully aware that the use of 'I' after 'is' is rather stilted, and that all but the most pedantic of grammarians would opt to use 'me' instead.)

Comment: Cf. ["I am who am"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_that_I_Am)

Comment: Can you compare some real, cited examples, showing their contexts? Otherwise, doesn't it boil down to how poetic you want to be? In any case, how does "stilted" apply?

Answer (score 0):

Asking Google produces this

> Getting relative pronouns like "who" to agree with verbs can seem tricky. But it's actually quite easy. The pronoun "who" takes the same number and person as its antecedent, in this case "I." So "It is I who am" is correct in this case.

Answer (score -1):

According to COCA https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/, "it is I who am" is correct.             [image]                          ! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSuo5.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure if such a survey of common usage implies correct usage

Comment: @ChinG Ultimately, common usage wins. For example, we've generally abandoned our second person singular, useful though it can be.

Comment: What would be wrong with 4? You should not equate popularity with correctness.